# VC dimension of infinite cones

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

What is the VC dimension of infinite $d$-dimensional cones? ( single cones not double).

I would say $2d + 1$ or $O(d^2)$

Does anybody have any reference or ideas?

Comment: I think the question is perfectly clear and not research level.